# How does mounting apps in Express work

Tags: node.js, express

So I've seen [TJ's guide to creating modular Express-apps](https://vimeo.com/56166857), followed it to good effects, but want to know more about the details of how it works, however a search gives me no answers.

**In short I am wondering:**  When mounting apps in Express, what parts of the apps are shared and what parts are not?

Some examples to clarify my question:

app.js:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser()); 

app.use(loginApi); //loginApi is an express app 

app.listen(3000);
```

This example works. But if I place the `app.use(loginApi)` before `app.use(express.bodyParser());` , the body parser will not be available in the loginApi subapp. Why is that?

Another example:

submodule.js

```
var app = module.exports = require('express')();
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('nifty middleware');
        next();
});
```

app.js

```
app.get('/funtimes', fn);
app.use(submodule); 
app.listen(3000);
```

Now in this example, If I understand it correctly, the `/funtimes` route will not be affected by the submodule middleware for all routes. But what about the rest of the routes of app.js ? Will they be affected? And what if I add another module, will it be affected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I place the app.use(loginApi) before app.use(express.bodyParser()); , the body parser will not be available in the loginApi subapp. Why is that?

That's because of the way Express handles requests. Any incoming request starts at the top of the middleware stack, starting with `app.use()` stack.

Middleware are simply functions that have the function signature `function(req, res, next)` which either call `next()` if they want to hand off the request to subsequent functions, or send a response themselves. You define a 'middleware chain' of a bunch of these functions (many are provided by express, like `express.logger()` and `express.compress()`.)

So in the following scenario:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
var loginApi = require('./api/index.js')
app.use(loginApi);
app.use(app.router);
```

then an incoming request will first hit `app.use(express.bodyParser())`, parsing `req.body`. Then that function calls its internal `next()`, passing it to the next function in the middleware chain (`app.use(loginApi)`). The loginApi app has its own middleware chain, but the requests already have `req.body` set from the outer app. If the loginApi doesn't send a response, the request will continue to `app.use(app.router)` and at that point the requests will go to the routing functions you set up in your outer app.

So the answer is: A mounted app will have the middleware functions shared, which are placed before the line `app.use(loginApi)`

Answer (score 3):

Middleware runs in order (until one of the middlewares doesn't call `next()`).

If you `use()` your mounted app before `use()`ing `bodyParser`, the entire sub-app will run before `bodyParser` adds its properties.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking about is middleware. This confused me for a while. Middleware are the functions that run in order to take a request in and serve back a response. app.use() takes a function as its only argument. That function manipulates the request in a consistent way.

app.use is a lot like app.all("*").

The order matters. For example, you might want to run a validator before serving the response.

One thing I learned recently is that you can pass an array of middleware functions to a route. For example

```
app.get("/whatever",[
    function(req,res,next}{
        ...validation...
        next();
    },
    function(req,res) {
        ...actions....
        res.send(200);
    }
```

]);

The next callback tells express to run the next function in the middleware. Middleware can also modify the request object. This is used a lot in authentication. For example, you'll see req.user getting defined from the database so in later middleware you'll be able to refer to properties of the user. But, it can also be used for a ton of other stuff.

Comment: Incidentally you don't even need an array, you can just pass multiple handler functions to `app.get('whatever', fn1, fn2, fn3)`

Comment: This is not totally correct. You can use app.use() to 'mount' a subapp at a relative directory. For instance, `app.use('/products', productService)` would utilize the `productService` middleware/application for all paths matchinging '/products', which are not caught by an earlier route.