# Send URL string to other script with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-mapping

I am starting to learn Node.js, using Express with Jade and Mongoose as my default toolbox. I used to develop in PHP, migrated to Python, and learned MVC through Django. Having a large client-side JS game and some inspiration from Mozilla.org, I am willing to make a multiplayer game -- and saw this as a noncommercial opportunity to learn Node: I can take my time with it.

However, I ran into a problem. I'm not trying to write an MVC system on my own, just to separate my site's "apps" like most MVCs do. The question is probably basic -- having this chunk of code:

```js
app.get(/^blog/, function(req, res) {
    require("./blog")();
});
```

... I understand the basics of Node/Express' URL masking, however I need to pass the rest of the URL string (everything that's after `mysite.com/blog`) to another URL parsing script, inside the `blog`app.

I googled around for a while and couldn't find a good solution. I even found a full tutorial on building an MVC scheme in Node and Express written for an older Express version, but that's a bit over the top for now. Can you provide me a simple solution?

I think `blog/index.js` should look something like this:

```js
module.exports = function(urlstring) {
    if(urlstring.indexOf('post') != -1) {
        // do stuff...
    }
    else if(urlstring === '/') {
        // return home.jade or something
    }
};
```

I hope I'm being clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use a mounted Express app.

Comment: What do you mean? You know, I'm new to Node et al...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19306084/34397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With express there is no need to parse your URLs on your own. I guess you'll want to build your blog URLs somehow like this

/blog           Show a list of blog posts
/blog/post/1    Show blog post with id '1'

With express 4 you can set up  a router for your blog path or a mounted app. Mounted apps allow you to let an app handle all sub URLs of a base URL path. [See the express documentation for more detail](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use).

I'd like to demonstrate how you can use the express 4 router together with the mounting feature of express to build blog routes.

```
// Set up express app
var app = express();

// Set up  a router
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // Show a list of blog posts
}

router.get('/post/:id', function(req, res) {
  // Show a single blog post 
}

// Mount router
app.use('/blog', router);
```

A benefit of this solution is that your routes registered in the router always get relative URLs with out the `/blog` prefix so you may reuse your blog routes in some other project under a URL like `/companyblog`.

Comment: Thanks! Is that different from using `app.use` to require an external app? The external file would have a new `app = express()`, that after all relative URL checking code would `module.exports = app` to the main one.